# ScrollViewer is displayed but cannot scroll and the contents go off the window to the bottom

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a wpf usercontrol and i have a scrolviewer where i have added the vertical scroll bar as Auto. The Scroll bar is creating but not allowing to scroll that. Below is the code.

XAML File

```
<ScrollViewer  x:Name="viewer" CanHorizontallyScroll="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Height="296" Margin="10,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanVerticallyScroll="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Width="186">
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Textblock are added dynamically to the stackpanel via Code. The problem is data getting displayed but the vertical scroll bar is not allowing to scroll as it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"VerticalAlignment" = "Top"` to `StackPanel`

Comment: Tried with VerticalAlignment = top also its still the same

Comment: Updated the XAML file in my actual post

Comment: Ah! And remove VerticalAlignment from ScrollViewer. Right now, when you add TextBlock it enlarges StackPanel and it enlarges ScrollViewer. StackPanel should be able to grow, so we need VerticalAlignment not to be Stretch (default), but Top. While ScrollViewer should not grow and should have VerticalAlignment = Stretch

Comment: Its still the same. Looks the content is in Readonly mode like the Textblock and scroll bar all are disabled and not allowing to click. How do we change that

Comment: Ok, going further :) Try to remove `CanVerticallyScroll="True"` from `StackPanel`.

Comment: Removed un wanted things and stil the issue is same

Comment: Wait, where's VerticalAlignment=Top for the StackPanel - this way it will always keep the same size as ScrollViewer. Try:

`<ScrollViewer x:Name="viewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="296" Margin="10,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="#FFB0AEAE" > <StackPanel x:Name="grey_block_stackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Width="186" VerticalAlignment="Top">`

Comment: Like i have said you in previous comments VerticalAlignment="Top" adding is not working out and looks the entire stack panel is disabled . how do we fix that. It would be a great help if you can help me in fixing this

Comment: Actually, you're right - VerticalAlignment = Top gives nothing. I've created mini application and used your code as is - and everything worked. I filled it with a lot of text blocks and scroll is there and working. Can you attach code how do you fill StackPanel with textblocks? And, just to be sure - you've set Background color for ScrollViewer with some gray color - sure you're not mistaking this color it as being disabled?

Comment: The sample code i have added in another Chanel. Can you take the code from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897878/stackpanel-inside-scrollviewer-is-in-readonly-mode?noredirect=1#comment120013061_67897878